# Which IP is sending most traffic to server

Tags: centos7

I have a `centos 7` server which started to get twice the amount of traffic two hours ago. how can I see which IP addresses generate the most traffic to my server?

The server is used to host `influxDB` and most of the traffic should be `udp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either `ss` or `netstat` to list connections. `netstat` is not installed by-default on CentOS 7, and you need to install it by using `yum -y install net-tools`.

Whilst using these tools, `-at` option will display all TCP connections and `-au` option all UDP connections. To get the output faster, use the "n" option to prevent ss from resolving ip addresses to hostnames, i.e. you should use `netstat -nt` and `ss -nt` for TCP, `netstat -nu` and `ss -nu` for UDP connections. If looking for all the listening sockets, use `-l` option with others. For instance, `ss -lun`.

You can also pipe some commands together to limit the output you want to get, for instance you can use `cut` and `grep` commands for getting more specific results. For example :

```
ss -lun | grep :8086 | uniq -c | sort -n
```

---

There are many tools you can benefit from. BTW, you can also install monitoring tools such as `iftop` - install them by using `yum -y install iftop`. That might help you a lot.